# Chilkat 9.5.0.49 support GCM cipher suites?

Tags: vb.net, chilkat

I am using the chilkat.http class to do a synchronous request to a server that accept only this 4 cipher suites:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030) 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)

with 9.5.0.49 i get "handshake failure" error: i have not tried the new version of the chilkat on this application because it run with framework 4.0 and the latest version don't compile

i don't know if all tls 1.2 cypher suites are supported by my version of chilkat dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Chilkat (v9.5.0.80) should solve the problem.

Comment: Updated to 9.5.0.80 and it works.
I have also tried the older 9.5.0.60 and it works too.